# Определение самого длинного слова в файле C++

Tags: c++, строки, файлы

Помогите, пожалуйста я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в роботе с файловыми строками поэтому не могу понять как исправить код.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void open_f(fstream from,fstream into){
from.open("D:\\f.txt", ios::in);
into.open("D:\\g.txt", ios::out);
if (!into.is_open() || !from.is_open() )  { 
cerr<<"Error input file"<<endl;
exit(1);
}
}

void close_f(fstream from, fstream into){
from.close();
into.close();
}

void reading(fstream from, fstream into){
string word,our_word;
string *pointer= word,  *second =our_word;
from>> *pointer;
int len = strlen(*pointer);
while(!from.eof()){

    word =" ";
    from >> *pointer;
    if(strlen(*pointer) > len){
        len = strlen(*pointer);
        our_word = word;
    }

}

into<<our_word<<" is the longest word un a file. It's has " 
<<strlen(*second)<<" characters";

}
main(){

fstream from, into;
open_f(from, into);
reading(from, into);
close_f(from, into);


}
```

Comment: Зачем его исправлять?

Comment: просто отсортировать массив слов по по длине слова и все и потом выбрать первый элемент массива

Comment: @Санитариум сортировка не рациональна, есть другие методы